# How to use imageview and textfield on uitableview cells at the same place on different conditions

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, ios6

I have to implement UiTableView with three conditions.

1. In one condition I have to show text like "Invite".
2. In second condition I have to show text like "Invited".
3. In third case I have to show Image if invited person has joined.

When I use only text change it is working fine but when I replace textfield with imageview then randomly it shows textfield and Imageview.

What I have pointed out that the table methods are called so fast that some of the conditions are not read by the compiler.Even if I have put conditions, it sometimes enters the loop even if its value is false.Like this case.

My code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ExampleCell";

NSLog(@"indexpath ==%d",indexPath.row);

ExampleCell *cell = (ExampleCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[ExampleCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSDictionary *dic=[self.FriendsDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UILabel *Label=(UILabel *) [cell viewWithTag:202];
Label.text=[dic objectForKey:@"name"];

NSString *FriendsIdArrayString=[FriendsIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 UIImageView *Image=(UIImageView*) [cell viewWithTag:203];

UIButton *Button=(UIButton*) [cell viewWithTag:201];
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


if([self.InvitedFriendsArray count]==0)
{
   [Button setTitle:@"Invite" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    for(int i=0; i< [self.InvitedFriendsArray count];i++)
    {
        NSString *InvitedFriendIdString=[self.InvitedFriendsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        
        InvitedFriendIdString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",InvitedFriendIdString];
        
        InvitedFriendIdString=[InvitedFriendIdString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        
        FriendsIdArrayString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",FriendsIdArrayString];
        
        FriendsIdArrayString=[FriendsIdArrayString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                 [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
        
        if([self.GetConnectedFriendsArray containsObject:FriendsIdArrayString])
        {
            NSLog(@"IndexPath.row====%d",indexPath.row);
            
                [Button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            
            Image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"graph.png"];
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@""];
            
            if([self.InvitedFriendsArray containsObject:FriendsIdArrayString])
               {
                   [Button setTitle:@"Sent" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                   break;
               }
               else
               {
                   [Button setTitle:@"Invite" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                   break;
               }
        }
    }
}

// Configure the cell.
[cell setFlickrPhoto:[ImageUrlArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;

}
```

Comment: Can you post more code that how you are loading data so that i can guide you better about how to handle TableView delegate methods?

Comment: I guarantee it is something to do with how they are being dequeued.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I have edited my question with my code.

Comment: Is it safe to not use reusability of UiTableview.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you the right way. You have a tabůe view which is dynamically loaded based on the data loaded from somewhere ? expecting web....

The table view is throwing ***NOT DISPLAYED CELLS*** away. So if you are changing the cells programatically there is a problem.

Everytime the view scrolls down and your cell becomes hidden the cell is released from memory... And as it is displayed it is completely reloaded. So the method cellForRowAtIndexPasth: is being called.

So I suggest you to have an array or any reasonable structure, where you will store the values of the connected users, especially the row index. Then in you cellForRowAtIndexPath: method you just check if the cell was modified. If yes so display required information, if not, just return unmodified cell as usually.

I suggest you to read docs and UITableDataSourceDelegate and UITableViewDelegate and methods description.

[Table View delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate)
[TableViewDatasource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

in the data source you will be interested especially in method :
***tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:***

Comment: Thank You for your response.Please see my edited question where you can better understand my problem and suggest me a way out.

Comment: Do you have sections in your table view ?

Comment: Is it safe to not use reusability of UiTableview.